# EF CodeFirst - cannot create database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am getting error while trying to run my MVC application

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Passages_dbo.Localizations_ToID' on table 'Passages' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors'
```

I`ve seen many posts but I couldn't get what should I do now.
There are my models:

```
  public class Passage
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int FromID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("FromID")]
        public Localization FromLocalizaton { get; set; }
        public int ToID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ToID")]
        public Localization ToLocalization { get; set; }
        public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AdditionalTime { get; set; }
        public bool Weekend { get; set; }
        public int Seats { get; set; }
    }


public class Localization
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string StreetAdres { get; set; }
}
```

Passage has two foreign key refers to Lozalization with one to one relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came from this:

> Passage has two foreign key refers to Lozalization with one to one relationship

Because by default those two relationships are required in `Passage` (look at foreign key `FromID` and `ToID` there are not `Nullable<int>` or `int?`) hence Code First create cascade delete action on those relations. However two cascade deletions will be applied on the same table which is not allowed.

To correct this issue, you have two solutions:

Make one of the foreign key property `Nullable<int>` which by default not create a cascade delete action on that relationship.

Or you can disable cascade delete action by using Fluent API like this :

```
// Assuming that you want to disable cascade deletion with ToLocalization
modelBuilder.Entity<Passage>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.ToLocalization)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```